# Segmenting a list of lists in Python

Tags: python

I have a list of lists all of the same length. I would like to segment the first list into contiguous runs of a given value. I would then like to segment the remaining lists to match the segments generated from the first list.

For example:

```
Given value: 2

Given list of lists: [[0,0,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,3], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]

Return: [ [[2,2,2],[2]], [[3,4,5],[9]], [[1,1,1],[1]] ]
```

The closest I have gotten is to get the indices by:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> import operator
>>> x = 2
>>> L = [[0,0,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,3],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]]
>>> I = [[i for i,value in it] for key,it in itertools.groupby(enumerate(L[0]), key=operator.itemgetter(1)) if key == x]
>>> print I
[[2, 3, 4], [8]]
```

This code was modified from another question on this site.

I would like to find the most efficient way possible, since these lists may be very long.

EDIT:

Maybe if I place the lists one on top of each other it might be clearer:

```
[[0,0,[2,2,2],1,1,1,[2],3], -> [2,2,2],[2]
 [1,2,[3,4,5],6,7,8,[9],10],-> [3,4,5],[9]
 [1,1,[1,1,1],1,1,1,[1],1]] -> [1,1,1],[1]
```

Comment: Its not clear how you are getting the expected output. can you please explain a little on how you are getting the expected output.

Comment: @PrashantKumar Break the first list into segments of continuous runs of the value 2. Find the indexes of those elements in the first list. Get the values from the other lists at those indexes, grouped in the same manner as the segments from the first list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` to create a list of groups in the form of a tuple of starting index and length of the group, and use this list to extract the values from each sub-list:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

def match(L, x):
    groups = [(next(g)[0], sum(1 for _ in g) + 1)
        for k, g in groupby(enumerate(L[0]), key=itemgetter(1)) if k == x]
    return [[lst[i: i + length] for i, length in groups] for lst in L]
```

so that:

```
match([[0,0,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,3], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]], 2)
```

returns:

```
[[[2, 2, 2], [2]], [[3, 4, 5], [9]], [[1, 1, 1], [1]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l=[[0,0,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,3], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]]

temp=l[0]

value=2
dict={}
k=-1
prev=-999
for i in range(0,len(temp)):
    if(temp[i]==value):
        if(prev!=-999 and prev==i-1):
            if(k in dict):
                dict[k].append(i)
            else:
                dict[k]=[i]
        else:
            k+=1
            if(k in dict):
                dict[k].append(i)
            else:
                dict[k]=[i]
        prev=i
output=[]
for i in range(0,len(l)):
    single=l[i]
    final=[]
    for keys in dict: #{0: [2, 3, 4], 1: [8]}
        ans=[]
        desired_indices=dict[keys]
        for j in range(0,len(desired_indices)):
            ans.append(single[desired_indices[j]])
        final.append(ans)
    output.append(final)
print(output) #[[[2, 2, 2], [2]], [[3, 4, 5], [9]], [[1, 1, 1], [1]]]
```

This seems to be one of the approach, this first creates the dictionary of contagious elements and then looks for that keys in every list and stores in output.

Comment: I have to go through it. Honestly it is a bit more complicated than I was hoping for. Sorry.

Comment: Ya actually it's much simpler to understand than previous version, it's just that I have implemented everything from scratch so code looks bigger XD.